# Cannot update entity with spring Crude Repository

Tags: java, spring, repository

I am absolute beginner in Spring and need some help. Code below is service layer and is intended to update organisation entity in CrudeRepository, but it only saves new organisation. Just can't imaginate what is wrong.

```
if (repository.exists(organisation.getId())) {
    repository.save(organisation);
}
```

Organisation.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organisations")
public class Organisation implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Version
private Integer version;

@NotNull
@Size(min=3, max=100)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(length = 100)
private String name;

@Column(name = "full_name")
private String fullName;

private long inn;

private long kpp;

private String address;

private long phone;

@AssertTrue
@Column(name = "is_active")
private boolean isActive;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it only saves new organizaton"? Does it add additional duplicating row into database table with the same id?

Comment: it works like this: trying to update the organization with id=3, I get an old version of the organization with id=3 and a new one with id=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your organization object is not managed by spring (it's a raw object, not a managed entity), try finding the object first and then updating the java object and finally save.

```java
Long id = ...
if (repository.exists(id)) {
    Organization organization = repository.getOne(id);

    // ...
    // Update objects field e.g. organization.setName("New Name");
    // ...

    repository.save(organisation);
}
```

Note you're using the `@Version` annotation, when the current version is null spring considers the entity as new. So this field shouldn't be null to update instead insert.

Comment: "Probably your organization object is not managed by spring" - But saving works just perfectly, how? I tried your solution - don't work either(

Comment: How do you get currently your organization object?. Using the getOne doesn't work either?. When you execute `repository.getOne(id)` you receive a managed entity instead of a normal java object created with `new Organization()`.

Comment: I've tried this:

'Organisation orgToUpdate = repository.findOne(organisation.getId());
           if (orgToUpdate != null) {
                if (organisation.getName() != null)     orgToUpdate.setName(organisation.getName());
            repository.save(orgToUpdate);
            }'

not working

Comment: https://github.com/danailKondov/BItask/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/bellintegrator/practice/orgs/service/impl/OrganisationServiceImpl.java

Comment: Ok, does it thrown an exception? or create a new row?

Comment: it works like this: trying to update the organization with id=3, I get an old version of the organization with id=3 and a new one with id=4

Comment: Ok but you commented the first part of the code right? i mean the lines 56-60, and uncommented 62-69.

Comment: Yes, i've tested them separately

Comment: What about the content of version? note that it cannot be null, look my update.

Comment: thank you very much, everything has finally worked! спасибо)